# asp.net mvc - How i convert local file path string to http url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After saved upload file, i got local url of this file, how i convert it to http url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string PathMap(string path)
{
    string approot = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.TrimEnd('\\');
    return path.Replace(approot, string.Empty).Replace('\\', '/');
}
```

source : http://www.aspapp.com/forums.asp?ForumId=11&TopicId=3536